# Setting Handlebars Attribute by Model Property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to set the class of a `<tr>` to either `#warning` or `#success` depending on the percentFree attribute of my Server Model. This is my Handlebar template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">

<h1>Virtual Image Overview</h1>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Machine Name</th>
            <th>Drive</th>
            <th>Total Size</th>
            <th>Used Space</th>
            <th>% free</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each controller}}
        <tr {{bindAttr class="status"}}>
          <td>{{name}}</td>
          <td>{{drive}}</td>
          <td>{{totalSize}}</td>
          <td>{{usedSpace}}</td>
          <td>{{percentFree}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

And this is my model:

```
Dashboard.Server = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  drive: DS.attr('string'),
  totalSize: DS.attr('number'),
  usedSpace: DS.attr('number'),
  percentFree: DS.attr('number'),
  status: "",
  setStatus: function() {
    if(this.percentFree <= 0.50) {
      this.status = "warning";
    } else {
      this.status = "success";
    }
  }
});
```

Although the class of the `<tr>` is never actually updated. Is there a more efficient (correct) way to go about this?

I have also tried `status: this.setStatus()` and

```
setStatus: function() {
  if(this.percentFree <= 0.50) {
    return "warning";
  } else {
    return "success";
  } 
}
```

With no luck

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good place to use an `itemController` for each of your child views within the `{{each}}` view.

Change your `{{each}}` helper to contain an `itemController` property with the value `server`.

```
{{#each controller itemController="server"}}
```

This will tell Ember to create an instance of `App.ServerController` for each server in the collection. The server model will become the `content` property of each item controller. Then you implement `App.ServerController` like this:

```
App.ServerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  status: function() {
    if(this.get('percentFree') <= 0.50) {
      return "warning";
    } else {
      return "success";
    }
  }.property('percentFree')
});
```

We extend `Ember.ObjectController` so that the controller proxies all properties from your model objects. We implement `status` as a computed property that depends on `percentFree`.

Also remove everything about status from your model.

Read more about the `{{each}}` helper in the [Ember.js API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each).

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two values I would do the following:

```
<tr {{bindAttr class="percent_status:warning:success"}} >
```

In your model:

```
  percent_status: function() {
    return this.percentFree <= 0.50 ? true : false;
  }.property('percentFree')
```

You can bind to a property value:

```
<tr {{bindAttr class="percent_status"}} >
```

Once things in your view start to get more complex and you need special classes and other logic I tend to move everything into an actual view.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/99/edit

Comment: And what if I wanted to add a third value, such as `#error`? which I plan on adding eventually.

Comment: Updated answer with one additional example. Again once you move beyond basic functionality it's probably better to think about custom views. Any time I've wanted to solve something complex in a template I just make it a view and that complex thing becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Actually, I tried your code, and they all default to "true." Even though there should be two warnings and two successes.

Comment: I've got this exact code working in one of my apps. Maybe hit me up on IRC and I can help troubleshoot more.